# Data Providers for BeforeMethod capabilities

Tags: java, testng, appium

Is there a way to use Data Providers for `BeforeMethod` function?
I would like to run parallel tests for number of different devices, so I would like to use parameters to setup capabilities. But I want to have a different way than using `testng.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data passed to the test by the data provider in your `BeforeMethod` by having `Object[]` parameter.

```java
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Object[] data) {
    //.......
}
```

Assume the following code:

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "dataOne")
public void testMethodOne(String one, int two) {
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dataTwo")
public void testMethodTwo(int one) {
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] dataOne() {
    return new Object[][]{ {"a", 1} };
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] dataTwo() {
    return new Object[][]{ {1} };
}
```

In order to get the data passed by the data provider before it reaches the test methods, you define a before method as below. I have added `Method m` parameter as well. This would help to identify the running test case. `Object[] data` contains the data passed by the data provider. If you have added this argument, then testNG would automatically pass the data to the before method.

```java
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method m, Object[] data) {
    if(m.getName().equals("testMethodOne")) {
        String x = (String) data[0];
        int y = (int) data[1];
    } else if(m.getName().equals("testMethodTwo")) {
        int x = (int) data[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but I dont understand, could give  a small exemple? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @laxsore you wanted to get the data passed to your test case from the dataprovider to your beforeMethod as well right?

Comment: That's right, but Im not ure how can I pass data from Object[]data. Can you give an example?

Comment: @laxsore I have added some relevant information in the answer to make it more clear.